# Websphere: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application

Tags: jsf, websphere-9

I migrated my application tomcat 7 to web sphere 9 version.server started successfully but when i try to load the page,getting below error.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions!
If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.

A typical config looks like this;

### org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener

```
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder._getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:286)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:206)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:342)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.load(ServletWrapper.java:1385)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1029)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:963)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:289)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
```

what should I do to fix it? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you bundle some JSF implementation jar with your app? if so you should not, WAS v9.0 comes with its own bundle implementation jars
If it was your intention to override the jsf implementation jars, then yous should look at the WAS documentation on how to do this. More info in the [WAS v9.0 doc here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tweb_jsf22.html)

Comment: thanks its working. overridden the jars using concept of shared library.

Answer (score 0):

I have same error in servlet listener config like above. But in my case I change folder Websphere to default installation (C:\swdtools\IBM\Websphere). Folder Websphere must inside folder C:\swdtools\IBM. Then my error solve.